# Is it possible to return a value while dismissmodelviewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I want to return a value while dissmissing the modelview controller , to the previous view .I dont want to use a notification or setting value to global string , I want to do some thing like this .

```
 NSString *Val=[self presentModalViewController:ViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

and while dismissing it should return the value .

Is there any way to do this .? Thanks in advance .

Comment: You can create protocol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow steps to create custom protocol.

in **ViewController.h**

```
@protocol textSendProtocol<NSObject>
-(void)sendText:(NSString *)strText;
@end
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property(nonatomic,strong)id <textSendProtocol> delegate;
@end
```

in **ViewController.m**

```
if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(sendText:)])
        [self.delegate sendText:@"yourText"];
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

in other view controller in which you present ViewController say **ExampleVC**

```
@interface ExampleVC ()<textSendProtocol>
@end


ViewController *obj = [[ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
obj.delegate = self;
[self presentViewController:obj animated:YES completion:^{}];

-(void)sendText:(NSString *)strText
{
    // you wil get text here.
    NSLog(@"%@",strText);
}
```

Maybe this will help you.

Comment: @Sat--VcanShakeTheWorld-- did you get any error or what? i'm not missing anything.

Comment: NO errors/ warning but the method is not getting called . I am not missing any of the steps you followed .

Comment: have you set delegate to self when you present view. and before dismiss you have to call protocol.

Comment: I am presenting view through segue , I managed this to storyboard , But am creating an object for the secondclass and delegate to self in viewdidload .

Answer (score 2):

You should read this guide on using Storyboards and returning data from one view controller to another with segues. This is the newer way of doing things on iOS. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/ThirdTutorial.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011343-CH10-SW1